# Getting average in pandas dataframe when there are NaN values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and I would like to add a row at the end of dataframe to show the average of each column; however, due to NaN values in Col2, Col3, and Col4, the mean function cannot return the correct average of the columns. How can I fix this issue?

```
       Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4


1      A       11      10      NaN
2      B       14      NaN     15
3      C       45      16      0
4      D       NaN     16      NaN
5      E       12      23      5
```

P.S. This is the dataframe after getting average (`df.loc["mean"] = df.mean()`):

```
       Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4


1      A       11      10      NaN
2      B       14      NaN     15
3      C       45      16      0
4      D       NaN     16      NaN
5      E       12      23      5
Mean   NaN     Nan     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is columns are not filled by numbers, but string repr, so first convert them to numeric by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
cols = ['Col2','Col3','Col4']
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(float)

df.loc["mean"] = df.mean()
print (df)
     Col1  Col2   Col3       Col4
1       A  11.0  10.00        NaN
2       B  14.0    NaN  15.000000
3       C  45.0  16.00   0.000000
4       D   NaN  16.00        NaN
5       E  12.0  23.00   5.000000
mean  NaN  20.5  16.25   6.666667
```

Or if some non numeric values use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`:

```
cols = ['Col2','Col3','Col4']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))

df.loc["mean"] = df.mean()
```

Comment: I used the same code, but it still returns NaN for Col2, 3, and 4

Comment: @amiref - first is necessary convert to numeric.

Answer (score 2):

You can set [`skipna=True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) when calculating the mean:

```py
df = df.mean(axis=0, skipna=True).rename('Mean').pipe(df.append)
print(df)

Col1  Col2   Col3       Col4
0       A  11.0  10.00        NaN
1       B  14.0    NaN  15.000000
2       C  45.0  16.00   0.000000
3       D   NaN  16.00        NaN
4       E  12.0  23.00   5.000000
Mean  NaN  20.5  16.25   6.666667
```